# Lsd radix sort + counting sort confusion

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I got a bit-based LSD radix sort working, but am confused on something I'm having to do to get it to work. In my LSD_radixsort function, r is my max bit represented with bits = (2^r)-1. My for-loop then goes through as long as bits/exp > 0. Though, when I make bits as an int type, It doesn't completely sort my array. When I make it a double, it sorts the whole thing. If i'm dealing with decimals, won't the loop never break since it will always be some small number that's greater than 0? Here is my code:

```
#include "lab8.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void countSort2(unsigned int arr[], int n, int exp);
unsigned int getMax(unsigned int arr[], int n);

void LSD_radixSort (unsigned int * A, int size, int r)
{


    // Find the maximum number to know number of digits

    double bits = pow(2,r)-1;


    // Do counting sort for every digit.

    for (int exp = 1; bits/exp > 0; exp *= 2)
    {
        countSort2(A, size, exp);
    }


}


void countSort2(unsigned int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int *output = new int[n]; // output array
    int i, count[2] = {0};



    // Store count of occurrences in count[]

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[ (arr[i]/exp)%2 ]++; 

    // Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual position of
    // this digit in output[]

    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    // Build the output array

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%2 ] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[ (arr[i]/exp)%2 ]--;
    }

    // Copy the output array to arr[], so that arr[] now
    // contains sorted numbers according to curent digit

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];


}


int main()
{
    unsigned int b[10] = {43,351,25,24,52,65,43,1,4,9};
    LSD_radixSort(b,10,5);
    int i = 0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

When I run it with double bits, my output array = 1,4,9,24,25,43,43,52,65,351

When I run it with int bits, my output array = 65,1,4,9,43,43,52,24,25,351

Any idea on why this is happening? Shouldn't I want my type to be an int?

Comment: I would suggest using ints and bit-shifts instead of `pow`, which is inexact. For example `2^k = 1<<k` and `(a / (2^k)) % 2 = (a>>k)&1`

Comment: Would I need to only change that one line, or include that throughout the code?

Comment: I only glanced over your code. I suggest you to try and fix it yourself via debugging, that is really not Stack Overflow's task

Comment: Shouldn't the second for loop with count be | for (i = 1; i < n; i++) |  count[i] += count[i - 1]; | ? (currently it is i < 2 instead of i < n.

Comment: Count only has 0 - 1 index